# When to use winrt::make vs constructors?

Tags: winui-3, c++-winrt

These two code fragments seems to be having same affect

```
if (!m_mainWindow)
{
    m_mainWindow = winrt::make<App1::implementation::MainWindow>();
}

if (!m_mainWindow.Content())
{
    m_mainWindow.Content(winrt::make<App1::implementation::ShellPage>());
}
m_mainWindow.Activate();
```

---

```
if (!m_mainWindow)
{
    m_mainWindow = App1::MainWindow();
}

if (!m_mainWindow.Content())
{
    m_mainWindow.Content(App1::ShellPage());
}
m_mainWindow.Activate();
```

Is there a reason I should be using winrt::make instead of directly calling constructors. Microsoft docs seems to insists I should be using winrt::make, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two code fragments are equivalent only if your projected opted into uniform construction, using cppwinrt's "-opt" flag as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/author-apis#opt-in-to-uniform-construction-and-direct-implementation-access

If you haven't opted in,the second code fragment will call `RoGetActivationFactory` to retrieve the factory and create an instance of the class, followed by `ActivateInstance` and `QueryInterface`, which is typically undesirable when you are dealing directly with that component's implementation. That page does a good job of explaining all the details.